# intellij with gradle multi project not showing source files in packages view

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have created a gradle multi project. When I switch files view to "Packages" view, no source files are shown.

I have tried restarting and invalidating the cache.

Confirmed that sources and resources are set correctly in module settings (third screenshot)

I'm using intellij ultimate 2022.3.3

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share a project to reproduce?

Comment: @Andrey Here is a project generated from `gradle init` command https://github.com/AlahmadiQ8/gradle-multi-project-example

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there was a bug, which will be fixed with the 2023.1.1 IDE update: [IDEA-264248 Empty gradle modules in packages view](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-264248/Empty-gradle-modules-in-packages-view)

Comment: From 2022.1.something to latest 2023.whatever, this worked to resolve our issue.